# Flutter fontsize in web

Tags: flutter

I have an application that works in mobile devices. I want to make this work in web, but i have a problem about font sizes. I give all the font sizes depends on screen's width. In desktop browsers, this makes a lot of problem. How should i solve this problem? What's the best approach and what's the quickest way to do this?
Here's a sample Text widget, almost all the text widgets are like this:

```
Text(memberDutyBasicViewModel.price.toStringAsFixed(2),
          style: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: size.width / 23)),
```

Answer (score 0):

in my own way to do multi platform settings (font size, etc), i would use some way to identified the current device. like if you run your app on web, but that user like to use the browser in small windows size which make it into a tablet view. this is how i do it:

```dart
class Responsive {
static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 730;

static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1190 &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 730;

static bool isWeb(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1190;
}
```

then in your text you can do:

```dart
Text(
      memberDutyBasicViewModel.price.toStringAsFixed(2),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: white,
        fontSize: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
            ? 20
            : Responsive.isTablet(context)
                ? 15
                : 10,
      ),
)
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i'm looking for. Another question, i have a lot of text widgets, and i should do this for all of them, is there any quick solution for them to apply this for all or should i go one by one?

Comment: create a fontSize variable and set it on those text, or you could create a text widget that have fixed font size value