# Flutter responsive fontSize

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

I've got a file called text_styles.dart which contains many different TextStyles like that (without a class or something else):

```
TextStyle subheadingTextStyle = TextStyle(
  color: blackColor,
  fontSize: 20.0,
  height: 1.7);
```

I call this TextStyle in other files with
`style: subheadingTextStyle`

Now I want to resize the font size depending on the screen size like described here: [Flutter fontsize in web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659826/flutter-fontsize-in-web)

So I changed my subheadingTextStyle:

```
TextStyle subheadingTextStyle = TextStyle(
  color: blackColor,
  fontSize: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
      ? 20
      : Responsive.isTablet(context)
      ? 15
      : 10,
  height: 1.7);
```

But I get an error that the context is undefined (because I try to access context outside of its scope).

What's the best way to fix that? Or is there any other (better?) way to dynamically resize the font size depending on the screen size?

Comment: I would say best way is leaving the font size as general,[14sp is just enough for all device].You can check `TextTheme`

Comment: but it's about a subeading, for that the size in desktov view must be larger than 14

Comment: Currently, I follow like `Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium` check https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: "Now I want to resize the font size depending on the screen size like described here" No.  You don't.  You really don't.  If you think you do, trust me, you don't.

Comment: Why not? @RandalSchwartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to use your method what u described then u need to handle like this below

```
TextStyle subheadingTextStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.black,
  fontSize: 20.0,
  height: 1.7,
);

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Hello!',
      style: subheadingTextStyle.copyWith(
        fontSize: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
            ? 20
            : Responsive.isTablet(context)
                ? 15
                : 10,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Responsive {
  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 730;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1190 &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 730;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1190;
}
```

But my suggestion is: make responsive based on device using any of this packages
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil
or
https://pub.dev/packages/sizer